# i want to draw some points(A,B,C,D,E) and link all these points into a custom map?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose that i have a set of points. How can i draw those points on a custom map (i made it myself) and like them together? 
[image]

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than this!

Comment: Take a look at the Google Maps API documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

The specific feature you want to use are called Overlays, and allow you to do precisely this.

Comment: @RichardConnamacher I don't think he is using google maps. He is talking about custom maps. He needs to be specific on how he constructed the map to begin with, say it's a HTML5 Canvas element. He can have elements in respect of the points he is talking about on top of them. Linking them under a common object will help him achieve what he is asking for. But I am not sure what is he talking about.

Comment: @Shouvik: He didn't make that background image himself. :) http://goo.gl/maps/8S5qa

Comment: Thank you for anwsering me, I did make the background map myself. Anyway my project is done by now. it's not good as google map but at least it works some how. Thanks again :D

Comment: @hoantrung Submit your answer on the approach you followed. That should help other people who may encounter the same issue in the future! And congratulations on resolving the issue! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your map is one that you have constructed using HTML5 Canvas. You can define the map as an object by making use of a simple canvas library. Now I am also considering the Canvas Element itself is divided into grids, so you position all you objects (Like the map, the various points on the map) in respect to this grid. After you have all the positions at the appropriate place, you will need to associate the common objects you are looking to group together with a flag, say attribute Group with keys "Liked" or "notLiked". Now when your user clicks on any object to like it, the function searches for similar flags on the other objects and switches them to "Liked" state too. I hope this is what you are expecting? If you need code, give us a fiddle link to your code.